# top-K query processing algorithm

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql

A number of algorithms e.g. HRJN (Hash Rank Join:https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~ilyas/papers/rank_join2.pdf) have been proposed in relational databases for ranking and retrieving top-K results. Does any open source relational database like postgresql implement such algorithm by default (If yes what is the database name?).

Comment: Seriously?   At least try a little!

Comment: @nicomp I tried ..but I am really not able to get the answer. It will be very kind of you if you can please help me with this a bit.